# Is there any way that I can add UIScrollView in another scroll view?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

```
**
```

- I had added UIScrollView in another
  scroll view but its not working.
     I have also added UITextView in UIScrollView and vice-versa but its
  not working.
     If anybody has tried or can give some idea then pls...
     Thank you in advance.

  With Regards
     Gunjan Shah - iphone developer

**

Answer (score 0):

Since a UITextView IS a UIScrollView, it is not surprising you would have the same problem.

[This link](http://github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness/tree/master) has a lot of good information about tricky UIScrollView issues.  It should help you figure out what to do with your current issue as well as others you run into later.